# Inefficient IEnumerable Select Statement on XDocument

Tags: c#

I have the following code and it is working fine. However I am new to using "IEnumerable code" and it would seem obvious that it could be done better.

Basically I want all Region nodes in the XML and then the data I want to output in my Asp:repeater is nested quite deeply in the XML, but the 4 fields are all at the same level.

```
var xDoc = xmlDoc.ToXDocument();

var jobs = xDoc.Descendants("Region")
    .Select(x => new {
        jobName = x.Element("Location").Element("Department").Element("Brand").Element("Jobs").Element("Job").Element("JobName").Value,
        jobType = x.Element("Location").Element("Department").Element("Brand").Element("Jobs").Element("Job").Element("JobType").Value,
        jobURL = x.Element("Location").Element("Department").Element("Brand").Element("Jobs").Element("Job").Element("URL").Value,
        jobClose = x.Element("Location").Element("Department").Element("Brand").Element("Jobs").Element("Job").Element("JobCLDate").Value
    }
);

if (jobs.Count() > 0)
{
    careersListing.DataSource = jobs;
    careersListing.DataBind();
    careersListing.Visible = true;
}
```

I would be very grateful of any feedback with respect to making it more succinct

Thanks

Nigel

Answer (score 2):

You're right; this can be inefficient.

You can simplify it like this:

```
var jobs = from x in xDoc.Descendants("Region")
           let job = x.Element("Location").Element("Department").Element("Brand").Element("Jobs").Element("Job")
           select new {
               jobName = job.Element("JobName").Value,
               ...
           };
```

If you prefer to use method call syntax, you can pass a statement lambda expression that declares a temporary variable.

Answer (score 2):

If there is just one `Job` element for each region (which seems to be the case), why not just query for it directly?

```
var jobs = xDoc.Descendants("Job")
    .Select(x => new {
        jobName = x.Element("JobName").Value,
        jobType = x.Element("JobType").Value,
        jobURL = x.Element("URL").Value,
        jobClose = x.Element("JobCLDate").Value
    }
);
```

Another minor optimization: Use `Any()` instead of `Count()`:

```
if (jobs.Any())
{
    careersListing.DataSource = jobs;
    careersListing.DataBind();
    careersListing.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (jobs.Count() > 0)` can be rewritten as `if (jobs.Any())`.